# what is difference between useBlockLayout vs useAbsoluteLayout in react table?

Tags: react-table-v7

I am using react-table. I'd like to know the difference between **useBlockLayout**, **useAbsoluteLayout** and **useFlexLayout**. And what case can use these hooks in?

Answer (score -2):

check this documentation again.

https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useAbsoluteLayout

results of these 3 layout hooks will different on style.